# Why does tikz cycle not work and why are these two sets of nodes different?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,0) (A) {A};
   \node at (0,1) (B) {B};
   \node at (1,0) (C) {C};
   \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) node (A) {A} -- 
         (0,1) node (B) {B} -- 
         (1,0) node (C) {C} -- 
         cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Some of the subtitles of TikZ are a little confusing. The example above produces the following pictures

[image: cycle1] [image: cycle2]

In the first case, the lines don't enter the node labels, but the `cycle` command isn't activated. In the second, the lines enter the node labels, but the `cycle` command is activated. I naively thought the two pictures should be the same. Why are the pictures different? Why do the lines behave differently? Why does cycle behave differently?

There is a similar question here.

[Cycle option when drawing between nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/cycle-option-when-drawing-between-nodes-in-tikz)

in which the answer explains that "bare nodes" do not have zero size. But it doesn't explain why the nodes are treated differently in these two cases. The phrase "bare node" does not appear in the TikZ Manual.

Comment: I do not understand why you are saying that this is not explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/cycle-option-when-drawing-between-nodes-in-tikz). If you read it carefully, you'll see that it does explain why cycle does not work.

Comment: @marmot. Explanations are in the eye of the beholder. That answer does partial work, but is not complete. See below.

Comment: I do honestly not understand what is new in the answer even though I highly respect @percusse and lear a lot from his posts and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,0) (A) {A};
   \node at (0,1) (B) {B};
   \node at (1,0) (C) {C};
   \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this case you are placing some nodes centered on certain coordinates. Every node is, by default, a rectangle around its contents. It has some `inner sep` between its contents and border. These borders are not drawn by default, but they exist.

When you write `\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;`, Tikz tries to join node's centers but stopping lines on nodes' borders. Therefore you see two disjoint lines, one between `A` and `B` and another from `B` to `C`, but as it's not possible to close the cycle, because you don't have a continous path, there is no line between `C` and `A`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) node (A) {A} -- 
         (0,1) node (B) {B} -- 
         (1,0) node (C) {C} -- 
         cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this case as `percusse` already explained, your are drawing a closed path between certain coordinates

```
   \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle ;
```

and supperposing node on it. It's a different command which produces a different solution.

Comment: The key, I think, is that the two `\draw`s do quite different things, despite having an almost identical form. The first draws *three* separate paths through three existing nodes. The second draws *one* path and puts three nodes on that path.

Answer (score 6):

By bare nodes node names are meant. When you use the node name, TikZ tries to be smart and checks where the target is and calculates the point on its shape border. Same goes for the target.

So essentially you are creating 3 separate paths and the last one is a line hence when used with cycle you get the last line printed twice. Because cycle only draws back to the last continuous path starting point.

If you use actual coordinates instead of node names such as `(A.center)` it works again.

Comment: "By bare nodes node names are meant." But both pictures have named nodes. But they are different.

Comment: @pheon No not really. You are using coordinates to denote the points and placing nodes along the way without breaking the path. That is actually a very nice feature of TikZ syntax.

Comment: So `\draw (0,0) -- (0,1);` makes two `coordinates` (which I thought were a special type of `node`.) But `\draw (0,0) node (A)  {} -- (0,1);` makes two `coordinates` plus a `node` with a name at the same place as the first `coordinate`?

Comment: @pheon Yes exactly. Nodes are not coordinates. They are shape objects placed at the coordinates either given by `at (x,y)` or the last given coordinate on the path. But `coordinate` is a node shape. By coordinate here I mean standard points with x and y component.

Comment: You might get mad at me, but I really think that this very nicely explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/cycle-option-when-drawing-between-nodes-in-tikz). What am I missing?

Comment: In the first case, the third path starts at node C (`C.center` actually, because there is no direction, see below) with a `moveto` operator. Then `cycle` uses the `closepath` operator that closes the path to the starting point. Thus, the `-- cycle` can be translated to `(C.center) -- (C.center)`, not a very long line.

Comment: "Nodes are not coordinates". But are not coordinates nodes?

Comment: Would `\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);` be three paths but `\draw (A.center) -- (B .center) -- (C.center);` be one path? That would be subtle.

Comment: @pheon There is a terminology clash. Coordinates in TikZ are `(x,y)`. There is also a `coordinate` node shape. Just like `\node[circle]` you can make a `coordinate` node via `\node[coordinate]` which is a special type of node. TikZ also has a special shortcut for this shape and it is `coordinate` just like `node`. Basic need for such a shape is that you cannot insert a named coordinate `(4,3)` but you can insert `(4,3) coordinate (a)` on a path to refer to it later.

Comment: @pheon *That would be subtle.* When you read my last comment it's gonna be clearer I hope.

Comment: I think I get it. With a `coordinate` node type with a name, you can use the name of the `coordinate` to refer to the coordinate of that node and the latter coordinate is not a node.