# Defining points as nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In the following MWE, why does the segments don't go up to the points I have defined?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (B) at (2,4) {};
\node (C) at (5,0) {};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\coordinate` instead of `\node`. A node has a finite size, which what you are seeing here.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4057/134144 might be related.

Comment: To show the problem, add the option `draw` to yours `\node`. Ex: `\node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- (2,4) coordinate (B) -- (5,0) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]