# how to graph plane symmetry of a cube?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does any one know if I can do this figure in Latex?

[image]

I know I can make the cube by the following code but how I can put that plan in the middle and write those numbers below it?

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\caption{A labeled cube}
\begin{tikzpicture}\label{f1}
\foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
1/{( 0  , 0)}/{$3$}/below,
2/{( 4, 0)}/{$4$}/below,
3/{( .8, 1)}/{$7$}/south east,
4/{( 4.8, 1)}/{$8$}/right,
5/{( 0, 4)}/{$1$}/left,
6/{( 4, 4)}/{$2$}/south west,
7/{( 0.8, 4.8)}/{$5$}/above,
8/{( 4.8, 4.8)}/{$6$}/above
}
{
        \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
    }
\draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- (1);
\draw (5) -- (6) -- (8) -- (7) -- (5);
\draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- (2);
\draw[dashed] (1) -- (3) -- (4);
\draw[dashed] (3) -- (7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The answer to your question is yes, you can. Please look at [TikZ documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). What you want to achieve is really basic TikZ. If you encounter a specific difficulty with the code, please, feel free to edit your question.

Comment: @KersouMan please see edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the liberty to modify the name of your nodes in order that the name matches the label.
Then, using the `calc` library of `TikZ`, you can draw the middle plane by positioning it midway between two corresponding vertices and hash it using the `patterns` library.
The numbers below are then placed relatively to the cube, but you can decide to change the coordinates to whatever you like.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
            1/{(0, 4)}/{$1$}/left,
            2/{(4, 4)}/{$2$}/south west,
            3/{(0, 0)}/{$3$}/below,
            4/{(4, 0)}/{$4$}/below,
            5/{(0.8, 4.8)}/{$5$}/above,
            6/{(4.8, 4.8)}/{$6$}/above,
            7/{(.8, 1)}/{$7$}/south east,
            8/{(4.8, 1)}/{$8$}/right
        }{
            \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
        }
        \draw (1.center) -- (2.center) -- (4.center) -- (3.center) -- cycle;
        \draw (1.center) -- (2.center) -- (6.center) -- (5.center) -- cycle;
        \draw (2.center) -- (4.center) -- (8.center) -- (6.center) -- cycle;
        \draw (3) -- (1) -- (5);
        \draw[dashed] (5) -- (7) -- (3);
        \draw[dashed] (7) -- (8);
        
        \draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;
        
        \node (a1) at ($(3)!0.5!(4) - (0,0.5)$) {$1\rightarrow3$};
        \node (a2) at ($(a1) - (0,0.5)$) {$5\rightarrow7$};
        \node (a3) at ($(a2) - (0,0.5)$) {$6\rightarrow8$};
        \node (a4) at ($(a3) - (0,0.5)$) {$2\rightarrow4$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

**EDIT**

As per [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t)'s comment, it is indeed easier to replace the last four nodes by only one node with

```
\node[below] at ($(3)!0.5!(4) - (0, 0.2)$) {$\begin{gathered} 1\to 3 \\ 5 \to 7 \\ 6 \to 8 \\ 2 \to 5 \end{gathered}$};
```

The reason I still defined a coordinate relative to nodes 3 and 4 is because using `current bounding box.south` as a coordinate will center the arrows between node 3 and the abscissa of node 8 instead of centering them between nodes 3 and 4, which I prefer, aesthetically speaking, but these are only my tastes.

**EDIT 2**

The `center` of the nodes are used for `cycle` to work correctly as exposed in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/cycle-option-when-drawing-between-nodes-in-tikz).

Comment: A possibly easier method for the bottom part: `\node [below] at (current bounding box.south) {$\begin{gathered} 1\to 3 \\ 5 \to 7 \\ 6 \to 8 \\ 2 \to 5 \end{gathered}$};` (requires `amsmath`)

Comment: could you please what I have to do if I want the middle plane to be vertical?

Comment: Just replace the points appearing in the line `\draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;` to obtain the middle points of horizontal segments.

Answer (score 2):

Another faster possibility could be using the code provided by a suitably modified external tool called [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\tikzset{
pattern size/.store in=\mcSize, 
pattern size = 5pt,
pattern thickness/.store in=\mcThickness, 
pattern thickness = 0.3pt,
pattern radius/.store in=\mcRadius, 
pattern radius = 1pt}
\makeatletter
\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@pattern@name@_s15avq03h}{
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\mcThickness,\mcSize]{_s15avq03h}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize+\mcThickness}{\mcSize+\mcThickness}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize}{\mcSize}}
{
\pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
\pgfsetlinewidth{\mcThickness}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\mcSize+\mcThickness}{\mcSize+\mcThickness}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (51.5,111.59) -- (119.09,44) -- (268.5,44) -- (268.5,190.07) -- (200.91,257.67) -- (51.5,257.67) -- cycle ; \draw   (268.5,44) -- (200.91,111.59) -- (51.5,111.59) ; \draw   (200.91,111.59) -- (200.91,257.67) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da19543087105562518] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (119.09,44) -- (119.5,189.99) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da47003768107339416] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (119.5,189.99) -- (268.5,190.07) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9239497588287866] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (51.5,257.67) -- (119.5,189.99) ;
%Shape: Parallelogram [id:dp8851996353080123] 
\draw  [pattern=_s15avq03h,pattern size=6pt,pattern thickness=0.75pt,pattern radius=0pt, pattern color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0}] (118.88,126.67) -- (267.5,126.67) -- (201.12,191.67) -- (52.5,191.67) -- cycle ;
% Text Node
\draw (36,104.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (39.5,263.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$3$};
% Text Node
\draw (202.91,261.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$4$};
% Text Node
\draw (121.5,193.39) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$7$};
% Text Node
\draw (121.09,47.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$5$};
% Text Node
\draw (270.5,47.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$6$};
% Text Node
\draw (207,104.99) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$2$};
% Text Node
\draw (270.5,193.47) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$8$};
\end{tikzpicture}
$\begin{matrix}
1\to 3& \\
5\to 7& \\
6\to 8& \\
2\to 4
\end{matrix}$
\caption{bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]