# cube with a vertical plane inside of it

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code shows a cube with a horizontal plane inside of it. how I can make this plane vertical?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
            1/{(0, 4)}/{$1$}/left,
            2/{(4, 4)}/{$2$}/south west,
            3/{(0, 0)}/{$3$}/below,
            4/{(4, 0)}/{$4$}/below,
            5/{(0.8, 4.8)}/{$5$}/above,
            6/{(4.8, 4.8)}/{$6$}/above,
            7/{(.8, 1)}/{$7$}/south east,
            8/{(4.8, 1)}/{$8$}/right
        }{
            \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
        }
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- cycle;
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- cycle;
        \draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- cycle;
        \draw (3) -- (1) -- (5);
        \draw[dashed] (5) -- (7) -- (3);
        \draw[dashed] (7) -- (8);
        
        \draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;
        
        \node (a1) at ($(3)!0.5!(4) - (0,0.5)$) {$1\rightarrow3$};
        \node (a2) at ($(a1) - (0,0.5)$) {$5\rightarrow7$};
        \node (a3) at ($(a2) - (0,0.5)$) {$6\rightarrow8$};
        \node (a4) at ($(a3) - (0,0.5)$) {$2\rightarrow4$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Say this question follows this one: [how to graph plane symmetry of a cube?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557012/138900)

Comment: As I said in the comment to [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557020/184389), you have to change the points used in the line `\draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;`. This means that you change 1/3;5/7;6/8;2/4 either to 1/2;3/4;7/8;5/6 or to 1/5;2/6;4/8;3/7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to graph plane symmetry of a cube?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557012/how-to-graph-plane-symmetry-of-a-cube)

Comment: @KersouMan how I should change it to be vertical?

Comment: `\draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(2)$) -- ($(3)!0.5!(4)$) -- ($(7)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(6)$) -- cycle;` or `\draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(5)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(6)$) -- ($(4)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(3)!0.5!(7)$) -- cycle;` depending on which plane you want.

Comment: great. thanks. what is a logic behind that? is there any tutorial that I can read? for example what I should do for diagonal plane?

Comment: Before using any package, you should read the documentation. TikZ documentation can be found [there](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). The logic is just that, for example, `($(1)!0.5!(2)$)` is the point located midway between coordinates `(1)` and `(2)`. Then you compute the other points that you need and you join them with `--`. The `cycle` is here to close the path by joining the last point in the list to the first point in the list. For diagonal plane, you just join the vertices you want  by using `(1) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- cycle` as a list of coordinates for example.

Comment: However, I really encourage you to read [PGF manual](https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) which contains several complete and detailed examples in the first chapters.

Comment: A side note from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/cycle-option-when-drawing-between-nodes-in-tikz), you will need to use `(1.center) -- (4.center) -- (8.center) -- (6.center) -- cycle` for `cycle` to work correctly.