# Tikz cycle does not close

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (dl) at (-1,0) {dl};
\node (dm) at (0,0) {dm};
\node (dr) at (1,0) {dr};
\node (ul) at (-1,1) {ul};
\node (um) at (0,1) {um};
\node (ur) at (1,1) {ur};
\draw (dm) -- (ul) -- (dl) -- (um) -- (dr) -- (ur) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

If I understand the manual correctly, `-- cycle;` in the code should produce additional line joining "ur" back to "dm". Why is it not there?

Comment: I believe [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/cycle-option-when-drawing-between-nodes-in-tikz) should answer your question.

Comment: @ttnick Yes, definitely, thanks. I will mark this duplicate.